# Use Font Awesome star rating for radio buttons

Tags: html, css, magento, jsfiddle

I try to load some font awesome css to display star rating instead of the default radio buttons.

I use this for a Magento webshop, that uses star rating.
The default code is dynamic and looks like this:

```
            <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                    <td class="value"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /><label class = "full" for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>"></label></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried this JSFiddle, but I can't get it done, that it will fill the stars based on the review. So input 5 will be 5 stars filled. So also; http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/tLj2ybnu/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/tLj2ybnu/4/

Change:

```
.rating > label:before
```

To:

```
.rating label:before
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want to remove the radio buttons entirely. See this example http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it work that it will fill all other stars? So giving a review with 5 stars, it will fill 5 stars.

Comment: Almost, but it needs to fill all stars lined from left to right. Just like this example http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Answer (score 0):

It **cannot** work with your current HTML structure. It works **only** using a sequence of `<label>` attached via `for="idOfInput"` to some hidden `<input type="radio" />` preceding each label directly. All those elements must be next to each other, that is, on the same DOM Level, having the same parent element. Otherwise you would need some sort of *parent selector* in CSS - and that simply does not exist.

You linked exactly what you need yourself in a comment. Using an image instead of a character works almost identical, but the solution makes alot less CSS necessary.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpaZYJ

```css
.rating-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rating-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
}

.rating-star:hover,
.rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.rating-wrapper:hover .rating-star:hover,
.rating-wrapper:hover .rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star,
.rating-input:checked ~ .rating-star {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.rating-star,
.rating-wrapper:hover .rating-star {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('http://css-stars.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/stars.png') 0 -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-5" name="rating-input-1" />
  <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-4" name="rating-input-1" />
  <label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-3" name="rating-input-1" />
  <label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-2" name="rating-input-1" />
  <label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>
  <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-1" name="rating-input-1" />
  <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
</div>
```

> Found on
>   http://css-stars.com/css-star-rating/